# How to protect all pages in wordpress blog with .htpasswd

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have been trying to add htpasswd authentication to my wordpress blog for all pages. So that when a person tries to view a page he has to be a valid-user. I tried adding the following snippet to my .htaccess file but it does nothing.

```
<Files *>
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwords
AuthName "Private access"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</Files>
```

Is it really possible with wordpress sites? I searched online and found people protecting wp-login.php with .htpasswd but not the other pages.

 
Please help.

Comment: Where are you placing the `.htpasswd` and `.htaccess` files? Do you have a file at `/usr/local/apache/passwords`?

Comment: yes the passwords files is present.. and .htaccess file is where the wp setup is

Comment: I just tried adding what you added to the existing `.htaccess` file in a new WordPress install and it works fine for me.

Comment: Is there no effect at all? Make sure `AllowOverride All` is allowed in your Apache configuration. I believe it is now disabled by default on some installs.

Comment: @WillS I checked my apache configuration and it was messed up as i was experimenting to make it work. I made sure AllowOverride All was there in apache config and added the above snippet to my .htaccess in wordpress setup... it works finally! thanks alot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I 100% understand the question but could you not just wrap the content on single.php in a [is current user is logged in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)?

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // do content
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you set directory directive AllowOverride All
2. Make sure Apache server has read permission on the passwords file
3. Use htpasswd cli to set credentials